# for loop nested array length cannot read property error

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop through this nested array in this function and when i do i get this error when i call the validateCred function in the findIndividualCards function 'let checkArray = array[array.length - 1]' ^

'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

here is the code

```
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];


// Add your functions below:
function validateCred(array){
  let checkArray = array[array.length - 1]
  array.pop()
  for(let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(array.indexOf([i]) % 2 != 0){
      let oddArray = array[i] *= 2;
      if(oddArray > 9){
        oddArray -= 9;
      }
    }
    array.push(checkArray);
    let total = 0
    for(let j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
      total += array[j];
      if(total % 10 === 0){
    return 'Valid';
  } else {
    return 'Invalid';
  }
  }
}
}
console.log(validateCred(invalid2))


function findInvalidCards(array){
  let invalidCards = []
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
      validateCred(array[j])
      if(array[j] === 'Invalid'){
        invalidCards.push(array[j])
      }
     
    }

}
 return invalidCards;
}


console.log(findInvalidCards(batch))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a logical error in your loop used in findInvalidCards. I'm not 100% sure what your validateCred() is doing, but this might help you in finding the problem. Note that `if(validateCred(array[i]) === 'Invalid')` line.

```js
function findInvalidCards(array){
  let invalidCards = []
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
      if(validateCred(array[i]) === 'Invalid'){
        invalidCards.push(array[j])
      }
    }
  }
  return invalidCards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the offending statement is `validateCred(array[j])` that is called within a nested loop and results in all of the elements of array to be popped. Should you use `validateCred(array[i][j])` instead?

I have not looked closely at the code and what it does. Moreover, you should get in debug mode, put a breakpoint in there and step through your code.